# Woocommerce with the Mystile theme - Theme overwrites not working?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, themes, overriding

i feel like i'm missing something really really stupid here.. i've got an ecommerce shop set up using the Mystile theme with woocommerce. I've read all over for hours about theme overwrites for the shop itself and any possible reasons as to why changes i've made are not showing.

My template directory for the overrides are in [mytheme]/woocommerce/ In the admin panel it says the overrides are going through.

Does anyone have any ideas at all?

Comment: So you want to change theme files or woocommerce?

Comment: I want to change the theme layout FOR woocommerce. EG: The Features widget.